# Count how many times a single checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I count how many times a checkbox is toggled from unchecked to checked?

```
<input type="checkbox" id="auto_<?= $sub_module_id ?>" onclick="test(<?= $sub_module_id ?>)" />
```

My JavaScript code:

```
function test(sub_module_id){
    $('#auto_'+sub_module_id).is(':checked'); //returns true,
    // I want to count when checked
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by count? Something like this? `if ($('#auto_'+sub_module_id).is(':checked')) { counter++; } ` ??

Comment: create a fiddle for this.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having a variable assigned with the count of how many times something is checked off why don't you assign the count to a data property since the count is specifically in relation to the element?

```
$(":checkbox").click(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    if (typeof ($this.data("count")) == "undefined") {
        $this.data("count", 0);
    };
    if ($this.is(":checked")) {
        $this.data("count", $this.data("count") + 1)
        alert($this.data("count"));
    }
});
```

Then when you need to access it you can use `$("#check1").data("count");`

http://jsfiddle.net/SeanWessell/xsazxevk/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function below to count the number of times a single checkbox has been checked:

```
var countChk = 0; 
function test(){
    if(jQuery('#auto').is(':checked'))
    {
        countChk = countChk+1;
        alert(countChk);
    }
}
```